# How to talk about a bend in the road

Tags: word-choice

> 警察によると、タイヤが落ちた**場所は右にカーブしています**。
>   According to police, the place where the tyres fell off was curving to the right.

Or in more natural English "...the tyres fell off on a right-hand bend".

Is 場所は右にカーブしています good Japanese? It sounds a bit strange to me. Are there better/alternative ways to talk about a left/right-hand bend, or is this already perfectly natural.

Comment: You misspelled "tires".

Comment: @itrasci So did you ;) In UK English it is spelt with a 'y'.

Comment: I know it's spelled that way in the U.K., which is why it's wrong.  :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「警察{けいさつ}によると、タイヤが落{お}ちた場所{ばしょ}は右{みぎ}にカーブしています。」

is actually a pretty natural-sounding sentence.  At least, I have no problem with it at all.

The native-speaking readers will undoubtedly know that it is the ***street*** (and not the 場所) that is 右にカーブしている.  In other words, this 「場所」 refers to a specific "spot/place/point" on that street and it happens to be where the street curves to the right.

> 「タイヤが落ちた場所は右にカーブしています」

means:

> 「タイヤが落ちた場所は、**道路{どうろ}が**右にカーブしています」

By the Japanese standards, however, the 「道路が」 part can sound slightly superfluous in a context where one is clearly talking about an incident occuring on a street.